# Identifier 'image' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a member

Tags: html, angular

Edit :: The output is added. I getting the output successfully, but I just don't know why I am getting this error. [image]I had already done this before but now I am facing this error. I had tried using "?" and "!!" but still not fixing. What is this and how to fix this..
Edit ::

html

```
 <div class="container" *ngFor="let data of data">
     <a href="{{ data.url }}"> //error in url ( Identifier 'url' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a member )
         <img src="{{ data.image }}"> // error in image ( Identifier 'image' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a member )
     </a>
 </div>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-technology',
  templateUrl: './technology.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./technology.component.css']
})
export class TechnologyComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [];

  constructor(private apiservice : ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiservice.getTechUrl().subscribe(async (data : any) => {
      this.data = await data.articles
    })
  }
}
```

## I found the solution for this

I had just changed the  data = []; to data : any; and there is no error and i also got the output without any error.

Comment: **1.** Not sure of the need for mixing async/await. **2.** Variable in controller is called data and the local variable in *ngFor is also called data. It might lead to collision. Try using other name: <div class="container" *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item?.url }}...

Comment: I already tried changing the data to item and now i tried removing the async/await but same problem

Comment: What does `this.apiservice.getTechUrl` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I found the solution

I just changed the data = []; to data: any; in the .ts file and then there is not error;

but I still don't know what is the exact reason for that error.
I don't if I am right about this the Json file which I was receiving is of type object and storing inside the data of array given me the error but after changing the to data: any; I am not giving any specific type in here, it may be of any type so error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Error template syntax *ngFor=*"let **data** of **data**"
ngFor can't use check point name same array data name.

Try this

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of data">
     <a href="{{ item.url }}"> 
         <img src="{{ item.image }}"> 
     </a>
 </div>
```

hope help you

Comment: try print data `ngOnInit() {
    this.apiservice.getTechUrl().subscribe(async (data : any) => {
      console.log(await data);
    })
  }` and share output @KumaravelA

Comment: I am actually getting the output but i just need to know why it is showing me error @Ameer

Comment: @KumaravelA Let see output maybe error in data.

Comment: i have added the screenshot for you reference and i don't see any error in the console.log